# HTML: Local Background Image

Tags: html, background-image

I am trying to display an image as my background that has been saved locally within my Eclipse project.

My folder layout is as follows:

```
assets
    www
      myimage.jpg
      index.html
```

Currently, in my `index.html` file I have the following:

```
<body background-image:url("www/myimage.jpg")>
```

However, the background image is not appearing...

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you are going `inline` than it should be `<body style="background-image:url("myimage.jpg");">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Problem 1: You have placed a CSS rule in your HTML as if it was an HTML attribute (which it isn't).
- Problem 2: You have given a path that isn't relative to your stylesheet. Since you don't have a CSS file in your directory listing, let's assume you are using an inline stylesheet. The files are therefore in the same directory.

Move it to a ruleset in your stylesheet, and fix the path.

```
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("myimage.jpg");
}
</style>
```

Comment: or inline: `style="background-image: url("www/myimage.jpg");` Altho this is bad practice, but a fast way to check if the path is right etc.

Answer (score 0):

do it like quentin said.

furthermore you can do this:

```
<body style="background-image:url('www/myimage.jpg')">
```

Comment: Style attributes are more trouble then they are worth in the long run. I wouldn't recommend their use.